# Dell D630 New LCD (NO BIOS DISPLAY, Windows display OK)

Tags: windows-xp, resolution, laptop-display

I got a replacement LCD panel for a Dell D630 and installed it.  After reading some of the posts here this was a risky proposition, I know that now.  The problem is that the BIOS does NOT display with the new LCD.  Strangely enough Windows XP displays just fine, no problems.  Even on an external display BIOS does not show up but Windows does.  This unit has an Nvidia card but I was told that the original symptoms (external video fine, internal blank) meant that the Nvidia fix was not applicable here.  To make matters worse policy dictates that a BIOS password be used, right now I type the BIOS password blindly and get in on the 2nd or 3rd try.

Could a new inverter fix this (used old inverter with new LCD)?  Is there a BIOS display resolution setting I can access from Windows to fix this?  The unit is not a total loss as is but would be much more versatile if I could fix this.

Comment: If it works at all (or at least this predictably), it's not the inverter.

Comment: Great, thanks ... at lesat that's good to know!  :)